# OSQuery and Python extensions with virtualenv

Tags: python, monitoring, osquery

I'm using OSQuery throught osqueryi and/or osqueryd on Windows.

I've written some Python extensions (tables) and I try using virtualenv to run these Python extensions.

When I run osqueryi.exe and python extensions separately from command line, the extensions are loaded ok and I can query my python tables. In this scenario, I use virtualenv ok.

When I use extensions.load, with my Python extensions and

osquery.flags has the next content

```
--disable_extensions=false
--config_path=C:\ProgramData\osquery\osquery.conf
--config_plugin=filesystem
--logger_plugin=filesystem
--logger_path=C:\ProgramData\osquery\log
--extensions_autoload=C:\ProgramData\osquery\extensions.load
```

In this scenario, osqueryi.exe shows the next error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\osquery\extensions\my_table.ext", line 3, in <module>
    import osquery
ImportError: No module named osquery
```

First, I activate my virtualenv and later I run osqueryi.exe with this osquery.flags file

In both scenarios, I used the same virtualenv environment with external modules installed via pip.

How can I configure OSquery To use virtualenv with Python Extensions.

Thanks

Comment: After creating virtualenv, you need to install the external modules in the virtualenv.

Comment: Yes, I have installed the external modules in the virtualenv created

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue.
Looking source code I have seen an environment variable called OSQUERY_PYTHON_PATH

In Windows you should run something like this

```
set OSQUERY_PYTHON_PATH=<path to python.exe in virtualenv>
```